# LIKE Predicate in Java. Does it Exist?

Tags: java, apache-commons, predicates

I have a requirement in which we have to search an object from a list of it. For example if we have a list of Persons object

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

The User object would have first name and last name as parameters like this.

```
 public class User{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
  }
```

I need to perform a search in which if the user enters "raj" as input it should produce the same result as "LIKE" query.

I have used apache-commons predicate for doing. it worked well for "EQUALS".
But do we have any other class in apache-commons which can be used for LIKE queries.

Comment: What do you mean by ""LIKE" query"?

Comment: You don't need apache commons, you can do it directly with jdk.. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
userList
  .stream()
  .filter(user -> user.getFirstName().contains(input))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

?

`String#contains` will return true if... I don't really think I have to explain that.

This would return a list of all users where firstname contains the input.

Comment: @User404 Of course. When the version is not specified I just go for the newest, I don't like old things. (No offence to old people).